# Rank periods with different conditions in the same dataframe

Tags: r, rank

I would like to rank the rows of a dataframe with different criteria according some conditions.

I have a dataframe with the following data: sampling date, month of the smpling date, percentage of breeding individuals in the population and gregorian days.

I would like to rank the rows in a different way if they are inside or outside the period when more than 20% of the population is breeding (*breeding period*).
I have this information for many months but here I only write two:

```
    mydf <- read.table(text="sampling_date - month - breeder - gregorian_days
    1/1/00-1-0-1
    5/1/00-1-10-5
    9/1/00-1-50-9
    13/1/00-1-100-13
    17/1/00-1-30-17
    21/1/00-1-20-21
    25/1/00-1-12-25
    29/1/00-1-3-29
    1/2/00-2-10-33
    5/2/00-2-20-37
    9/2/00-2-50-41
    13/2/00-2-80-45
    17/2/00-2-50-49
    21/2/00-2-51-53
    25/2/00-2-30-57
    28/2/00-2-10-61"
    , sep="-", header=TRUE)
mydf
```

I would like to rank **within each month** the rows:

(1) before the first row with a value lower than 20 write A

(2) from the first value higher than 20, start ranking, but ranking the rows each 3 real days (e.g. rank 1 = days 5,6,7; rank 2 = days 8,9,10...). So all rows within the breeding period don't have to be continuous. It is possible that some ranks will not be added as the 4 for the first month.

To do this until the last row with a value higher than 20

(3) after the last row with a value higher than 20 put B

Below I have added the results that I would like to get

```
   sampling_date month breeder gregorian_days rank
1         1/1/00     1       0              1    A
2         5/1/00     1      10              5    A
3         9/1/00     1      50              9    1
4        13/1/00     1     100             13    2
5        17/1/00     1      30             17    3
6        21/1/00     1      20             21    5
7        25/1/00     1      12             25    B
8        29/1/00     1       3             29    B
9         1/2/00     2      10             33    A
10        5/2/00     2      20             37    1
11        9/2/00     2      50             41    2
12       13/2/00     2      80             45    3
13       17/2/00     2      50             49    5
14       21/2/00     2      51             53    6
15       25/2/00     2      30             57    7
16       28/2/00     2      10             61    B
```

The threshold to start the ranking may be a criterion based on the values of one column of the dataframe, or I can get the exact dates to define the different behaviours inside and outside the period breeding period.

For example with the thresholds

```
    Start<- c("9/1/00", "5/2/00")
    End <- c("21/1/00", "25/2/00")
```

All what I have got is to make a loop an for each month to change the values higher and lower 20 using the function `if` but I don't know how to make the ranking within the breeding period.

Could you help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've just corrected the object `mydf`. Now it should works perfectly.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(sampling_date=c('1/1/00','5/1/00','9/1/00','13/1/00','17/1/00',
                                 '21/1/00','25/1/00','29/1/00','1/2/00','5/2/00',
                                 '9/2/00','13/2/00','17/2/00','21/2/00','25/2/00','28/2/00'), 
                                  month=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
                                  breeder=c(0,10,50,100,30,20,12,3,10,20,50,80,50,51,30,10), 
                                  gregorian_days=c(1,5,9,13,17,21,25,29,33,37,41,45,49,53,57,61))

df$sampling_date <- as.Date(df$sampling_date,'%d/%m/%y')

df$rank <- do.call(c, by(df, df$month, function(x) { 
                      breeding <- x$breeder>=20 
                      first <- which(breeding)[1] 
                      start <- x$sampling_date[first]
                      ifelse(breeding,
                             as.integer(x$sampling_date-start)%/%3+1,
                             c('A','B')[(1:nrow(x)>=first)+1])
                      }))
df
##    sampling_date month breeder gregorian_days rank
## 1     2000-01-01     1       0              1    A
## 2     2000-01-05     1      10              5    A
## 3     2000-01-09     1      50              9    1
## 4     2000-01-13     1     100             13    2
## 5     2000-01-17     1      30             17    3
## 6     2000-01-21     1      20             21    5
## 7     2000-01-25     1      12             25    B
## 8     2000-01-29     1       3             29    B
## 9     2000-02-01     2      10             33    A
## 10    2000-02-05     2      20             37    1
## 11    2000-02-09     2      50             41    2
## 12    2000-02-13     2      80             45    3
## 13    2000-02-17     2      50             49    5
## 14    2000-02-21     2      51             53    6
## 15    2000-02-25     2      30             57    7
## 16    2000-02-28     2      10             61    B
```

---

**Notes:**

- I've coerced your dates to `Date` class using `as.Date(...,'%d/%m/%y');` to prepare for datewise arithmetic.
- I've leveraged the `by()` function for groupwise logic. I chose `by()` over `aggregate()` and `ave()` because the latter two can only work on one column at a time, but the logic requires multiple columns (specifically `sampling_date` and `breeder`), which `by()` supports. Also, `aggregate()` always combines the aggregated data with the input data.frame columnwise, forcing each group into a single row, so it is not generally suitable for multi-element return values; `ave()` and `by()` are required for that.
- In my solution, I precompute (1) a logical vector representing which rows are "breeding days" and which are not (`breeding`), (2) the first breeding day row index (`first`), and (3) the first breeding day `Date` value (`start`). Then I branch on breeding period with `ifelse(breeding,...)`.
- For breeding days, I do datewise subtraction of each day minus the start day, and use integer division by 3 (plus 1) to get the rank value.
- For non-breeding days, I index `c('A','B')` based on whether the non-breeding day occurred before or after `start`.